# importing modules node.js function overrides another function even without importing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in the following code i'm using expresjs

```
//index.js

app.use('/',routes());

//app/routes.js
module.exports = function() {

   express = require('express');
   const loggedUserProfileController = require('../controllers/LoggedUserProfile');
   const userProfileController = require('../controllers/userProfile');
   const router = express.Router();
   router.post('/get-logged-user-profile', loggedUserProfileController.getLoggedUserProfile());
   router.post('/get-user-profile-data', userProfileController .getUserProfile());

   return router;
   }
```

controllers

```
   //controllers/loggedUserProfile.js
  module.exports = 

  {
   getLoggedUserProfile:function(){

   return getLoggedUserProfile:function= (req, res, next) => {
          getUserCustomData();
     }
  }
  getUserCustomData(){console.log('logged user')}


  //controllers/userProfile.js
  module.exports = 

  {
   getUserProfile:function(){

   return getUserProfile:function= (req, res, next) => {
          getUserCustomData();
     }
  }
  getUserCustomData(){console.log('user')}
```

the output is `'user'`
the second getUserCustomData overrides the first one how is that possible regarding that i didn't import it in module.exports

Comment: Have you tried adding the getUserCustomData function inside the module that you're exporting and calling it by this.getUserCustomerData(), in my understanding you're declaring the function globally and then overriding it globally again.

Comment: yes i did and worked but the answer which i was looking for is using const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  A function definition is hoisted, declared, and assigned.  If you define another in the same scope after the previous one, the new definition will now overwrite the original.

Identifiers used in function statements/definitions are not **constants** and are therefore subject to re-assignment.  If you want it to remain static after creation you can do `const getUserCustomData = function () { ... }` instead and the second attempt to re-assign will throw an error for you.